# JQuery AutoComplete TextBox from database using AJAX PageMethods in ASP.Net is not Working in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I need to make the AutoComplete TextBox from database using AJAX and I have tried this.

Html code...

```
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.10.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.9.2/themes/blitzer/jquery-ui.css"
    rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("[id$=txtSearch]").autocomplete({
            source: function (request, response) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: '<%=ResolveUrl("~/Default.aspx/GetCustomers") %>',
                    data: "{ 'prefix': '" + request.term + "'}",
                    dataType: "json",
                    type: "POST",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    success: function (data) {
                        response($.map(data.d, function (item) {
                            return {
                                label: item.split('-')[0],
                                val: item.split('-')[1]
                            }
                        }))
                    },
                    error: function (response) {
                        alert(response.responseText);
                    },
                    failure: function (response) {
                        alert(response.responseText);
                    }
                });
            },
            select: function (e, i) {
                $("[id$=hfCustomerId]").val(i.item.val);
            },
            minLength: 1
        });
    });  
</script>
Enter search term:
<asp:TextBox ID="txtSearch" runat="server" />
<asp:HiddenField ID="hfCustomerId" runat="server" />
<asp:Button ID="Button1" Text="Submit" runat="server" OnClick="Submit" />
```

C# code

```
[WebMethod]
public static string[] GetCustomers(string prefix)
{
    List<string> customers = new List<string>();
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection())
    {
        conn.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["constr"].ConnectionString;
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
        {
            cmd.CommandText = "select ContactName, CustomerId from Customers where ContactName like @SearchText + '%'";
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SearchText", prefix);
            cmd.Connection = conn;
            conn.Open();
            using (SqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (sdr.Read())
                {
                    customers.Add(string.Format("{0}-{1}", sdr["ContactName"], sdr["CustomerId"]));
                }
            }
            conn.Close();
        }
    }
    return customers.ToArray();
}
```

It works fine in Chrome, Mozilla but not working in Internet Explorer 11 Compatibility Mode .. Is there a way to work it in IE Compatibility Mode ?
I want to correct the error in Compatibility Mode,..
In IE its showing an Error :

> JavaScript runtime error: 'JSON' is undefined

Comment: Regarding the 'JSON' is undefined error, make sure you don't have a comma after your last element in all your objects (including the returned from the server), and another thing - make sure you are not running IE in a compatibility mode for a really older version.

Comment: @Samuil Petrov I am running it in compatibility mode.. I want to correct it in this mode,

Comment: I understand, for some versions it works when "<!DOCTYPE html>" is added at the start of your document, if that does not fix your issue you can use some cross-browser JSON object library like json2.js: https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js (you just need to include the script and it will fix things)

Comment: It worked thanks @Samuil Petrov

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked

```
<script src="http://yandex.st/json2/2011-10-19/json2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

I just added json2.js now it is working in all browsers...

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/json2/20160511/json2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```